# how to find the worst-case complexities of the following algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

```
for (i = 0; i<= n-2; i++)
 do {
  j: = n-1 
  while (j > i)
   do {
    if A[j] < A[j-1] then 
      temp: = A[j] 
      A[j]: = A[j-1] 
      A[j-1]:= temp 
      } 
   j: = j-1 
  }
 }
```

from my understanding, I know that this is an insertion sort algorithm, and the worst-case scenario of insertion sort is O(n^2). I just don't know how to explain the steps to be followed to get to the answer

Comment: Take a look [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms) or with an [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/)

Comment: You have two nested loops that could run up to n-1 times, so indeed it is roughly O(n^2). Your code does not seem to be C language though, so wrong tag!

Comment: You tag [c], but the code presented is not valid C, and you don't seem to be asking a question specific to C.  If indeed the question is not actually about C, then please remove that tag.  If it *is* about C, then please convert your pseudocode to *bona fide* C code.

Comment: It also doesn't seem to be about data structures or artificial intelligence.  Please do not spam tags.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop runs for `j` in `[i+1, n-1]` (decreasingly). So it performs `n-1-i` comparisons, and at most this number of swaps.

The outer loop runs for `i` in `[0, n-2]`, making the total number of comparisons equal to

```
n-1 + n-2 + n-3 + ... 1
```

This is a triangular number.

Comment: Re "*This is a triangular number.*", i.e. x + x-1 + x-2 + ... = x(x+1)/2, which is O(x^2)

Comment: @ikegami: Tn-1, not Tn.

Comment: Re "*Tn-1, not Tn*", ...and O( (n-1)^2 ) = O( n^2 )